# Jython java.util.Date to string

Tags: java, python, datetime, jython, java.util.date

I am using Jython to call some Java code.  One of these java methods returns a Date.   How do I get a python str out of that?  I have this:  (context is the java object I sent into the Jython)

```
emailDate = context.getSentEmail().getCreateDate()
log("Email  date is:"+datetime.strftime(emailDate))
```

and I am getting this error:

```
unbound method strftime() must be called with datetime instance as first argument (got java.util.Date instance instead)  (execute) (PythonRunner.java:89)
```

How do i do this?

**Update**

so I added the imports statements like this:

```
from time import time
import datetime
```

And I am now getting this error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'strftime'  (execute) (PythonRunner.java:89)
```

Comment: You might need to import a time or date-time module.